# Vim: Remove comment character after double enter

Tags: vim

In Vim, I like the feature that allows you to auto insert comments after you have started a comment block. How would you make it so that you get a comment character(s) after a newline, but upon getting a second newline that comment is removed and you start a newline without a comment character. This would be helpful if you are working on a comment block and don't want to make anymore comments after that (in my case I also want to apply the same thing to markdown lists, treating */- as comment characters).

For example

```
// typing a comment
// (cursor here after hitting enter once)
```

And

```
// typing a comment

(cursor here after hitting enter twice)
```

Answer (score 4):

This mapping checks if the current line contains only comment leaders before deciding if it does `<C-u>` or `<CR>`:

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> getline(".") =~ '^\s*\(\*\|//\|#\|"\)\s*$' ? "\<C-u>" : "\<CR>"
```

Comment: I put that in my vimrc and try to type // then enter I get: `E15: Invalid expression: ^R=getline(".") =~ '^\s*\(\*|//|#|"\)\s*$' ? "\^U" : "\^M" `

Comment: Same here on Vim 7.2. Remove the `<C-r>=` to fix E15. I couldn't get the "or" part of the expression going, but this works for my purposes: `inoremap <expr> <CR> getline(".") =~ '^\s*\(#\)\s*$' ? "\<C-u>" : "\<CR>"` (it would be nice if it integrated with the language's comment syntax)