# vim: end comments and retain indentation

Tags: vim

I'd like to be able to end a run of comments but retain the current indentation. Is this possible either through an existing command or with a function?

I have `formatoptions -=o` and `autoindent` so I normally get by using `o` from normal mode - the cursor is on the next line, the indentation is correct and I'm in insert mode. I'm only worrying about single line comments (eg '*#*'s - as for shell, python etc).

I'm interested in how I can make this more general (particularly not dependent on my `formatoptions`). I'd like to have an `imap` for `;;` but I can't seem to find a straight forward way if I want to call a function (for example, to check whether I'm currently on a comment line).

I've played around with `<expr>` mappings and the expression register but either I lose the indentation (cursor ends up in the first column) or the comment continues. It seems like there might be a better alternative to either reimplementing the autoindent logic or trying to delete the extra comment characters. I've also tried saving/restoring formatoptions while using `normal o` but leaving insert mode when there's no other content on the line deletes the indentation.

I appreciate suggestions about how I should approach this.

Comment: It's probably easiest to `o` or `O` and `<c-w>` or `<c-u>`.  Have you taken a a look at Tim Pope's [commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary)?

Comment: Similar post: [Vim: Remove comment character after double enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222481/vim-remove-comment-character-after-double-enter)

Comment: Jason how about making that an answer?

Comment: @Ben It only works when you have `fo+=o`.  It doesn't handle closing comments as well, which is why it's probably better to adapt commentary.

Comment: If you DON'T have fo+=o then the comment leader is not inserted in the first place so no extra effort is needed to end the comment. Using `o` to start a new line already applies the current indentation rules.

Comment: “I'm only worrying about single line comments” – what currently goes wrong with single-line comments? Can you add an example editing task, with a sequence of keypresses, the text before, the actual text after, and the desired text after? (As I understand it, you’re thinking that one of those keypresses would be a custom mapping – but what are the keypresses surrounding it?)

Comment: If your problem is that indentation on a blank line is deleted when pressing `<Esc>`, then this mapping fixes that: `inoremap <Esc> x<BS><Esc>`.