# Vim setting or plugin that can remove comment leader on empty trailing comment lines?

Tags: vim, comments

Searching for this is difficult due to the overload of the word "leader" in Vim documentation.

Here are the (hopefully relevant) settings I have now:

```
formatoptions=croql
comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://
```

I want Vim to insert a new comment leader (`//`) on each new line, whether it wraps due to textwidth (`formatoptions=c`) or because I hit enter (`formatoptions=r`), but I want Vim to remove any automatically inserted comment leader if I escape to normal mode without entering any text on the new line. So the sequence `// text<Enter><Escape>` from insert mode should yield this:

```
// text
```

instead of this:

```
// text
//
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the blank line? or remove the line completely? If you are just inserting a blank like please take a look at the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16360472/438329

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222481/vim-remove-comment-character-after-double-enter