# Can I skip the auto-commenting after the last line?

Tags: vim, comments

I use `//` to mark comments in C files, and when I reach the end of a line and press Enter, Vim helpfully inserts the `//` at the beginning of the next line.

Usually that's what I want, but when I have finished inserting comments I have to delete that `//` to resume typing real code. It occurs to me that there MIGHT be a way to terminate the last comment line without getting the comment continuation. Ctl-Enter, Shift-Enter, Fn-Enter don't work, and Alt-Enter takes me out of Insert mode.

Is there a way to a) remain in Insert mode, b) open a blank line below, AND c) not add the `//`?

Comment: How about using `S` or `cc` to clear the line and start insert mode?

Comment: You can disable this feature complete like so: `set formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o` but I don't that is what you want. Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Disable_automatic_comment_insertion

Comment: [Vim: Remove comment character after double enter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26222481)

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way, but you can surely define a custom mapping that provides this, either by using workaround command sequences (`<CR><Esc>cc`, or `<Esc>o`), or by temporarily changing the `'formatoptions'` option that controls this.

In terms of editing efficiency, there's not much to gain over the alternatives (I usually just press `<C-u>` to clear the inserted comment prefix), so I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about that one. `<C-u>` is better than `S` or `cc` which I've been using until now, because those require you to escape insert mode first. I recommend using [this vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Recover_from_accidental_Ctrl-U) if you start using `<C-u>` though.